# Reorder a matrix according to a primary matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices.

Matrix 1:

```
 ID SEX AGE     TYPE DEATH
  1   F  32 DIABETES     0
  2   M  23  CONTROL     1
  3   F  33 DIABETES     0
```

Matrix 2:

```
ID AGE DEATH SEX    TYPE
 1  42     0   M CONTROL
```

How can I reorder the columns in matrix 2 in the same order as matrix 1 so that Matrix 2 reads:

```
ID SEX AGE    TYPE DEATH
 1   M  42 CONTROL     0
```

Comment: Those look like `data.frame`s; please clarify.

Comment: matrices or data frames?

Comment: As there are both character and numeric variables available in my example I  would say a data frame. My own data is a matrix though.  I would be grateful if you could provide a solution  for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data.frame,

```
df2[names(df1)]
# ID SEX AGE    TYPE DEATH
#1  1   M  42 CONTROL     0
```

For matrix

```
m2[,colnames(m1)]
#ID       SEX       AGE      TYPE     DEATH 
#"1"       "M"      "42" "CONTROL"       "0"
```